# How to set a specific size of a flex box container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As the title states, I want the container of a flexbox to have a specific width and height. However, I don't know what approach I can use. This is my code:

```html
<div class="container-gallery">
  <img src="gallery/img.png" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img3.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img4.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
.container-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* width: 67.5%; */
  justify-content: center;      
}

.container-gallery img{
  width: 15%;
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 8%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

I tried creating a parent `div` of the container gallery to center the children `div` and put a specific width in container-gallery. It does work; however, when you try resizing it, it doesn't center its content because of the set width on it. Something like this:

```html
<div class="container-gallery">
  <img src="gallery/img.png" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img3.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img4.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="gallery/img5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
.container-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 67.5%;
}

.container-gallery img{
  width: 15%;
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 8%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.main-gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

What can I do?
I'm pretty new to Flexbox so treat this as a newbie question.

It should be like this! the width and height. [image: desire output]

Comment: Can you provide some visuals (e.g. drawing) to better understand how you want your layout to look like in various screen dimensions?

Comment: hi! yes i already edited it, check it out. thanks!

Comment: Does setting "width: 100px" not work? Or whatever amount of pixels?

Comment: So, you want a specific number of images per row (like 3 in the screenshot), no matter the width of the page? Or you want a fixed size for the image?

Comment: it does work however it won't be centered anymore since the justify content take the width into consideration

Comment: i want it 3 per row as u just said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below CSS fixed your issue!

> please view in full screen for proper results!

[flex-grow: 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)

[flex-shrink: 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

[flex-wrap: 30.33%](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

The reason its not 33.33% or 1/3 is because to adjust for the margin!

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #191D2B;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.container-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-gallery img {
  flex: 0 0 30.33%;
  border-radius: 8%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.main-gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Gallery</div>
<div class="container-gallery">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" alt="">
</div>
```